# Retrieving JSON Object after new page load

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am not familiar with JSON handling in a web dev context, so would appreciate a little guidance.

I have a login utilising a web form - if a successful login has been made, a JSON array is returned as follows:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "message": "Login Successful",
    "user": {
        "name": "Foo Bar",
        "email": "foo@bar.com",
        "unique_id": "59bea8b7d56a63.8888888"
    }
}
```

My DB Operations returns the JSON to my Functions.PHP. I then do the following:

```
$response["result"] = "success";
$response["message"] = "Login Successful";
$response["user"] = $result;
$json = json_encode($response);
```

It's here that I am stuck because I want to send the encoded JSON to the web page that will be open on success, as I want to make further DB queries based on the user unique_id.

I have tried on page 1:

```
$response["result"] = "success";
$response["message"] = "Login Successful";
$response["user"] = $result;

$json = json_encode($response);


header('Location: http://example.co.uk/quiz/dashboard.php/'.$json);
```

Page 2

```
<?php
$data_get = $_REQUEST['user'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mydata =<?php echo $data_get; ?>;
</script>
```

But I have not been able to echo out the user data. I want to be able to retrieve the encoded array on page 2 and then decode it and store the name/email/unique_id in variables to use when needed on page 2.

Comment: Create a hash for the new page, then detect it and do something on it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You line:

```
header('Location: http://example.co.uk/quiz/dashboard.php/'.$json);
```

seams to be the problem.

If you really want to transfer the whole json string via GET request you need to define a name for it. try this:

```
header('Location: http://example.co.uk/quiz/dashboard.php?data='.$json);
```

And then on page 2 this is how you receive it:

```
$response = json_decode($_GET['data']);
```

After that you can access the $response array same as on page 1.

Btw: it might be easier to store the data in a [session](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Comment: Yeah, you were right, needed to update my header line. I ended up adding `echo $response->message. "</br>";
echo $response->result."</br>";
echo $response->user -> name."</br>";` That enabled me to access the data. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In your page 1

```
$response["result"] = "success";
$response["message"] = "Login Successful";
$response["user"] = $result;

$json = json_encode($response);


header('Location: http://example.co.uk/quiz/dashboard.php/?data='.$json);
```

In Page 2 you will get values like that

```
$data = json_decode($_GET['data']);

echo $data->message. "</br>";
echo $data->result."</br>";
echo $data->user."</br>";
```

Or if you want assign json to javascript variable then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mydata =<?php echo $_GET['data']; ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you are doing try this in file 2:

```
$decoded=json_decode(array_keys($_REQUEST)[0]);
echo $decoded->user;
```